# use javascript in a html tagg

Tags: javascript, html

I have these codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var screenWidth = window.screen.width;
var width_sides = (screenWidth - 980) / 2; 
</script>

<div id="not_important" width=""></div>
```

I want to set the width of the div equal to the result from the equation inside the javascript tagg. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="not_important" width=""></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var screenWidth = window.screen.width;
  var width_sides = (screenWidth - 980) / 2; 
  document.getElementById('not_important').style.width = width_sides;
</script>
```